# How can I connect to MySQL on a WAMP server?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

This might be ridiculously easy for you but I've been struggling with this for an hour... :(

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost:8080", "root", "mypassword");
echo($connect);?>
```

This is the code that I'm trying to run - you can see that I'm using 8080 as my port number and, of course, I have HTML codes as well.

However, it gives me the following error messages whenever I try to open the PHP file:

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\php_sandbox\index.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Error while reading greeting packet. PID=4932 in C:\wamp\www\php_sandbox\index.php on line 2

Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\php_sandbox\index.php on line 2
```

I don't know... what's wrong with this? Is it because of the port number?

Comment: MySQL normally listens on 3306. Why are you trying to connect to 8080?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Change localhost:8080 to localhost:3306.

Comment: It can be confusing since they don't tell you upon installation. If you want to put it out on the internet make sure you have a password for root since WAMP does not include one automatically. Cheers mate.

Answer (score 4):

Try opening Port 3306, and using that in the connection string not 8080.

Comment: Oh my god, how stupid I am... I thought that port-number belong to MySQL :S   Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 4):

Just Change the Connection mysql string to 127.0.0.1 and it will work