# Django sql connection failed

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have created new project in django and write mysql connection in it's settings file like :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'optdb',
        'User': 'root',
        'Password':'975',
        'Host':'127.0.0.1',
        'Port':'8080',
    }
}
```

Now i write command : `python manage.py syncdb` and that generates following error:

[image]
How to solve this error mentioned above?
Note: I have currently one user in my MYSQL WAMP SERVER that is root with host `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those keys should be in capitals.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'optdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD':'975',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'8080',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'optdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD':'975',
        'HOST':'127.0.0.1',
        'PORT':'8080',
    }
}
```

It's case sensitive...

Also, are you sure your mysql server is at port 8080? That's unusual. If unsure, just leave out that line and default mysql port will be used. See [How can I connect to MySQL on a WAMP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459006/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-on-a-wamp-server)