# Deploy php project in wamp server

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I have a php project which was designed in codeigniter mvc framework. Now i want to deploy it in wamp server but it is showing directory structure like

application,
www

And database also not connecting. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the files into the %yourpath%\www

Everything in here will be accessible from the browser, if the WAMP server is running.

To connect to your database you use the username: root, there is no password. The IP is 127.0.0.1.

Goodluck, here is a link to help you out.
[How can I connect to MySQL on a WAMP server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459006/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-on-a-wamp-server)

Comment: but somewhere has suggested we have to put project folder inside www folder in wamp server.

Comment: my project name is myapp it has codeigniter mvc structure i copied inside www folder in wamp is it correct way or not.Please help me